# Activate Approval, Collect Feedback, and Collect Signatures workflows for a site collection?

Tags: 2010, workflow, feature-activation

All workflows are active except for Approval, Collect Feedback, and Collect Signatures.

Everything I've read says to go to `Site Collection Features` and activate `Workflows`.  I've done this, but these three workflows are still inactive.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: what is the sharepoint version?

Comment: Sorry, I updated to include version.

Comment: Sharepoint foundation or server?

Comment: Sharepoint Server

Answer (score 0):

Check in 'Manage Site Features' as well - double check all workflow related such as Workflow Task Content Type - to this point...

I am not a big fan of the workflows in sharepoint that are included out of the box - they use tasks and become complicated / and not end user friendly.

Prefer, instead, to use a sharepoint designer workflow that leverages simple but customized notifications that are sent directly to users and get the information they need in front of them so they can quickly click a link, and and execute their decision.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.Stackexchange.com! Your contributions here are welcome, but we don't allow promotion of products in answers. Your other answer was in response to a question specifically asking for book suggestions which is fair enough, But for the avoidance of doubt I have edited this to remove possible advertising that doesn't seem essential to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Approval, Collect Feedback, and Collect Signatures Workflows in the list. Then you need to activate a **Workflows** Site Collection Feature.

Follow below steps

1. Navigate to your Site Collection
2. Go to Site Settings
3. Find the `Site Collection Administration` section, Under it click on `Site collection features`
4. Scroll down at bottom, find and activate **Workflows** feature.

Once you do above steps, you will be able to find the Approval, Collect Feedback, and Collect Signatures workflow templates.